# Is there a way in play-json to read a key/value map, remembering the original ordering?

Tags: scala, play-json

Given:

```
{
  ...
  "fruits": {
    "apple": { ... },
    "banana": { ... },
    "cherry": { ... },
    ...
    "watermelon": { ... }
  }
}
```

Is there a way in Scala to read this JSON map `fruits` of String -> object while remembering that the ordering of the keys was originally apple, banana, cherry ... watermelon?

*[below added because I was asked why I wanted this and to provide a test example]*

Normally I wouldn't care about the ordering (of a Map). I do not control the format of the input; it is a Map, not an Array. The real input is not fruits, it is alerts with alphanumeric keys, I just picked fruit names for simplicity. I am building test files based on the data. Suppose there were ten items in the first file, and I deleted "watermelon" (the 10th object) from the 2nd file. The code that read the first file put the objects in to a database. When it processes the objects (alerts), each produces an action. A test result is an `EventAction(id:Long,action:String)`. The `id` is an auto-increment Long from the database; I do not control that. After processing the first file, it turns out that the alert associated with "watermelon" was created with an id of 2, not 10. When I'm building my test for the processing of the second file (the one without "watermelon"), if I think the id will be 10, the test will fail not because I predicted the `action` incorrectly, but because I didn't know the `id` would be 2 instead of 10.

One of way of dealing with Map ("you shouldn't care about ordering so you won't get any clues as to the original ordering in the JSON file") is I can build *ad-hoc* SQL to find out what database `id` was created for each key, just for the tests. Before I write *ad-hoc* SQL (the company normally asks all DB interactions be through stored procedures written by a DBA), I thought, "Wouldn't it be neat, at the time of reading the JSON, to remember the ordering in the moment, before it is lost."

Comment: Why would you care about the order?

Comment: @TomerShetah It's for my testing. I build test files from real data. This particular data uses maps instead of arrays. I delete/edit objects as I build scenarios. I know which objects I modified (where they are in the file). I need to predict what the event ids in the DB will be as I build expected pairs of event Ids and outcomes. The event ids are tied to database insertion order.

Comment: Can you please add a sample test?

Answer (score 1):

Play-json(at least 2.6.9) parses js object from top to bottom collecting all fields to `content: ListBuffer[(String, JsValue)]`. When all fields in the object are parsed, then `JsObject` is instantiated via `apply` method

```
def apply(fields: Seq[(String, JsValue)]): JsObject = new JsObject(mutable.LinkedHashMap(fields: _*))
```

So the answer to your question: if you use the default `Reads` for `Map` from the library, the ordering is already kept.

Comment: Play-JSON 2.6 starts to get old, latest is 2.9

Comment: @cchantep Using 2.7.4 at the moment.

Comment: I am using the default Reads for Map. What I get is a HashTrieMap, and the elements appear unordered.

Comment: `Map` comes with no order assumption. Anyway your tests could easy do a `toSortedMap` to enforce key order (even if most of the test framework are able to compare unorderly and order as no meaning/guarantee in JSON repr).

Comment: @cchantep, even in 2.9.1 we have the following
```
  private[json] def createFieldsMap(fields: Iterable[(String, JsValue)] = Seq.empty): mutable.Map[String, JsValue] = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, JsValue]().asScala ++= fields
  }
  def apply(fields: collection.Seq[(String, JsValue)]): JsObject = new JsObject(createFieldsMap(fields))
```

and in fact `JMapWrapperLike` uses underlying java map

Comment: Did I say the contrary?

Comment: No, I'd just noticed that the implementation was changed :)